# Animate commits inside IDE to learn codebase, an idea?

Tags: version-control, codebase

Go back in time in the codebase and see the commits as an animated explanation of how the codebase was formed. a great way to get into a open source project?

For insance if you could play this inside Eclipse, so that the comments the time and the reason for the commit become clear.

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

A static (i.e. non-animated) version of "going back in time" is [EGit **`blame`**](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Finding_the_author_of_each_line_in_a_file) (annotations):

[image: EGit blame or annotations]

> Selecting the `Team > Show Annotations` action on file selections will open the editor and display an annotation ruler with commit and author information for each line in a file.
>   Hovering over the ruler will display a pop-up showing the commit id, author, committer, and the commit message.